# How to set focus a ref using React-Hook-Form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

How do you implement set focus in an input using React-Hook-Form, this is what their FAQ's "How to share ref usage" code here https://www.react-hook-form.com/faqs/#Howtosharerefusage

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const firstNameRef = useRef();
  const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input name="firstName" ref={(e) => {
        register(e)
        firstNameRef.current = e // you can still assign to ref
      }} />
      <input name="lastName" ref={(e) => {
        // register's first argument is ref, and second is validation rules
        register(e, { required: true })
      }} />

      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

I tried set focusing the ref inside useEffect but it doesn't work:

```
useEffect(()=>{
   firstNameRef.current.focus();
},[])
```

Neither does inside the input:

```
<input name="firstName" ref={(e) => {
    register(e)
    firstNameRef.current = e;
    e.focus();
}} />
```

Comment: can you reproduce this in a codesandbox?

Comment: @Bill here it is: https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-water-57w99?file=/src/components/react-hook-forms/ReactHookFormTest.js

Comment: your example worked just fine.

Comment: Your sandbox works fine. What's the problem?

Answer (score 18):

You can set the focus using the `setFocus` helper returned by the useForm hook (no need to use a custom ref):

```
 const allMethods = useForm();
 const { setFocus } = allMethods;

 ...

 setFocus('inputName');
```

https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/setFocus

Comment: new link: https://www.react-hook-form.com/api/useform/setfocus

Answer (score 6):

If you using Version 7, you can check this link in the docs

https://www.react-hook-form.com/faqs/#Howtosharerefusage

Answer (score 5):

Are you using Typescript?

If so, replace...

`const firstNameRef = useRef();`

With...

`const firstNameRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);`

Answer (score 4):

I can't comment (I don't have enough reputation), but without setting a timeout, `setFocus` didn't work. After adding a simple timeout from [Subham's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71826450/17133387), it worked like a charm!

PS: Even adding a timeout of 0: `setTimeout(() => setFocus(fieldName), 0)` works. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Did you find out the reason?

Comment: No, not yet. Still have no idea why

Answer (score 3):

```
useEffect(() => {
if (firstNameRef.current) {
      register(firstNameRef.current)
      firstNameRef.current.focus()
    }
}, []);

<input name="firstName" ref={firstNameRef} />
```

Got this from : https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/230

Answer (score 1):

```
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    setFocus, // here
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<FormFields>({
    resolver: yupResolver(LoginSchema),
    mode: "onTouched",
  });



useEffect(() => {
    setFocus("email");
  }, [setFocus]);
```

Comment: The most idiomatic answer, this should be much higher!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply use `ref={(el) => el.focus()}` to set the focus. The catch here is to make sure no other element within your page is also setting focus right after that `el.focus()` call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useMergeRefs` from Chakra to combine the focus ref and the refs that react-hook-form uses, and pass that on to the `input` component:

```
import { 
  Input,
  FormControl,
  FormLabel,
  useMergeRefs
} from "@chakra-ui/react";

const focusRef = useRef(null);

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
  <FormControl isInvalid={Boolean(errors.newRlName)}>
    <FormLabel>name</FormLabel>
    <Input
      type="text"
      {...register("name")}
      tabIndex={1}
      ref={useMergeRefs(editRef, register("name").ref)}
    />
    <FormErrorMessage>{errors.name && errors.name?.message}</FormErrorMessage>
  </FormControl>
</form>
```

[ref](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/issues/4792#issuecomment-934733711)